# Why doesn't `importlib.metadata.version` work on zip files?

Tags: python, python-importlib

According to the documentation, `importlib.metadata.version` should work on `dist-info` folders in ZIP files. However, if you run `pip install -t foo jedi-language-server` (though you can use any package), `zip -r foo.zip foo`, `PYTHONPATH=foo.zip/foo python -c "from importlib.metadata import version; version('jedi-language-server')"`, I get `importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for jedi-language-server`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it only works if the metadata is in the top-level directory; that is, you have to do `(cd foo; zip -r foo.zip .)`. It does not support nested directories.